# Slow WP_Query with 'OR' on meta_query

Tags: wp-query, filters, meta-query

Essentially, I'm trying to query using a filter for the args being fed into WP_Query() like so:

```
    public function filter_wp_query( $args, $template_slug ) {

        $args['post_type']         = 'post';
        $args['search_post_title'] = isset( $args['s'] ) ? $args['s'] : '';

        $args['meta_query'] = [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key'   => 'hide_thing',
                'value' => '0'
            ],
            [
                'key'     => 'hide_thing',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ]
        ];

        add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, &$wp_query ) {
            global $wpdb;
            if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_post_title' ) ) {
                $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb::esc_like( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
            }

            return $where;
        }, 10, 2 );

        return $args;
    }
```

This is being applied on the following filter:

```
$recent_items_args = apply_filters( 'my_template_manager_recent_articles_args', $recent_items_args, $_GET['my-template'] );
```

Which is being fed into WP_Query like so:

```
$recent_items_query = new WP_Query( $recent_items_args );
```

Normally this query (without the 'meta_query') takes no time at all and works perfectly. Additionally, it works great without the 'NOT EXISTS' check. But once I add in the 'relation' => OR along with the NOT EXISTS check, it slows way down -- to the tune of 12-15 seconds.

Is there a different/better way to do this that doesn't involve a huge override of the actual query being performed?

I've considered setting the 'hide_thing' meta value on all posts if there's no quick way to query for 'NOT EXISTS' and that will be my path forward, but I thought I'd ask you fine people to see if there's a way to modify the existing meta query so that it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the possible values of 'hide_thing'? Can you do a != on that value and thereby get rid of the OR and the NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: Thanks for following up! The possible values (for posts that have the meta value assigned) are 1 or 0, but I want to get the posts that either have it set to 0 or don't have the setting at all.

Comment: Then do a get_col for those post_ids with the value set to 1 and include them in WP_Query using post__not_in

Comment: Hmm.. I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks!